# Office365ActiveUsers Graph API call returning Not Found - We do not recognize this tenant ID

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get a Office 365 Active Users Report using the Microsoft Graph Beta API.

Calling `/reports/Office365ActiveUsers(view='Detail', period='d180')/content`) is returning:

```json
"error": {
    "code": "NotFound",
    "message": "We do no recognize this tenant ID {id}. Please double-check the tenant ID and try again.",
    "innerError": {...}
}
```

I've also tried `/reports/Office365ActiveUsers(view='Detail', period='d180')/content` and `/myorganization/reports/Office365ActiveUsers(view='Detail', period='d180')/content`.

Any ideas on how I can fix?

[image: Graph Playground Screenshot]

Comment: Are you able to run this report manually from the [O365 Admin Portal](https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/reportsUsage/LicenseActivity)?

Answer (score 0):

This has resolved itself after waiting a few days.

I did turn on auditing in Security & Compliance > Search & investigation > Audit Log search (i.e. https://protection.office.com/#/unifiedauditlog) but I don't know if that had any effect or not.

Thanks [@Marc LaFleur - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105518/marc-lafleur-msft) for your comment, I was getting the same error in the Admin portal when clicking on Export Report.